# Why is this concept not evaluated to true?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have the following code, to try implementing Applicatives (from pure functional programming) in C++ using concepts:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

// Maybe struct
template <typename T>
struct Maybe
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> _val;

    Maybe() {} // initialize _val with nullptr
    Maybe(T const& val) : _val(new T) { *_val = val; }
};

template <typename T>
Maybe<T> nothing() { return Maybe<T>(); }

template <typename T>
Maybe<T> just(T const& val) { return Maybe<T>(val); }

template <typename T>
bool isjust(Maybe<T> const& maybe) { return !!maybe._val; }

template <typename T >
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Maybe<T> const& maybe)
{
    if(isjust(maybe))
    return out << "just " << *maybe._val;
    return out << "nothing"; 
}

// Applicative concept, MVE with only pure (<*> works)
template<template <typename> class F, typename A>
concept Applicative = requires(A const& a)
{
    { pure(a) } -> std::same_as<F<A> >;
};

// implement this concept for Maybe
template <typename A>
Maybe<A> pure(A const& a)
{
    return just(a);
}

int main()
{
    // test applicative
    cout << pure(3) << endl;
    
    cout << "maybe is an applicative: " << Applicative<Maybe, int> << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It yields:

```
just 3
maybe is an applicative: 0
```

(tested both on g++ 10.5, and g++ 13.2 via Compiler Explorer).

Why is the Applicative predicate false ? It seems obvious for me that it should be true, since we define the function `pure` with the right prototype to fit the concept constraint.

EDIT: Now the mystery thickens... If I replace the line:

```cpp
{ pure(a) } -> std::same_as<F<A> >;
```

by

```cpp
{ pure<A>(a) } -> std::same_as<F<A> >;
```

I get a true `Applicative<Maybe, int, int>` with gcc 10.4, but false for gcc 13.2 ! Why is going on here ? Aren't the type inference capabilities of compilers supposed to be dictated by the standard ? So is it considered a bug in the older version of gcc ?

Comment: What happens if you add a `template <typename A> Maybe<A> pure(A const& a);` forward declaration, before the concept?

Comment: Note that we have [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it works in this case ! Though I don't like it, because I want to use the Applicative concept like a library, and be able to use it for several types (not just Maybe), without having to forward declare all of them before. I tried with more general forward declarations, like `template <template <typename> class F, typename A> F<A> pure(A const& a);` or `template <typename A, typename B> B pure(A const& a);` but it does not work in this case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but my main goal is to define a general Applicative concept, that could be used for several different template types. (Maybe is just a test type).

Answer (score 3):

In

```
requires(A const& a)
{
    { pure(a) } -> std::same_as<F<A> >;
};
```

so `pure(a)` (with `[A=int]`) in our case.

Primitive types such as `int` don't "trigger" ADL.
and so, function should be declared before their usage.

But for user type, ADL might be used, so `Applicative<Maybe, Maybe<int>>` is true ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6aeEWYEjv)).

Answer (score 0):

##### Why is the Applicative predicate false ?

In my opinion, the later gcc version (and clang) are right to evaluate this concept to `false`. For a clear explanation, let's use the following reduced example, with `static_assert` instead of runtime prints:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Applicative = requires(T const& cv) {
    pure(cv);
};

template<typename T>
T pure(T v) {
    return v;
}

static_assert(Applicative<int>);
```

**[Live demo (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/1oKa4aMWo)**

Conveniently with `static_assert`, the compiler politely explains why it evaluated the concept to `false`. Here's gcc 13.2 output with `-std=c++20 -fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=5`:

```
<source>:11:15: error: static assertion failed
   11 | static_assert(Applicative<int>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:15: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>:2:9:   required by the constraints of 'template<class T> concept Applicative'
<source>:2:23:   in requirements with 'const T& cv' [with T = int]
<source>:3:9: note: the required expression 'pure(cv)' is invalid, because
    3 |     pure(cv);
      |     ~~~~^~~~
<source>:3:9: error: 'pure' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation
<source>:7:3: note: 'template<class T> T pure(T)' declared here, later in the translation unit
    7 | T pure(T v) {
      |   ^~~~
```

Here's clang 17.0.1 with `-std=c++20`:

```
<source>:11:15: error: static assertion failed
   11 | static_assert(Applicative<int>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:15: note: because 'int' does not satisfy 'Applicative'
<source>:3:5: note: because 'pure(cv)' would be invalid: call to function 'pure' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    3 |     pure(cv);
      |     ^
```

gcc makes it extremely clear that we have 2 correct solutions: forward declaring `pure(T)`, or ADL (Argument-Dependent Lookup). As Jarod42 said, it's not possible to do ADL on a fundamental type like `int`. `pure(int)`'s declaration must be before `Applicative`'s definition for the concept to work as you expect.

##### Workaround: template specialization instead of ADL.

I suggest that you implement `pure` using template specializations, like the standard library implements hashing using `std::hash`. This is an extremely modular approach: users of the standard library specializes `std::hash<MyType>`, and `std::unordered_set<MyType>` just starts working, even if the specialization is done after the definition of `std::hash` or `std::unordered_set`.

```cpp
// Specializations must define Pure<T>::apply(T const&).
template<typename T>
struct Pure;

// forward definition of pure(T).
// The return type is fully left to Pure<T>'s specialization.
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) pure(T const& cv) {
    return Pure<T>::apply(cv);
}

// pure is always in scope of Applicative.
template<template<typename> class App, typename Arg>
concept Applicative = requires(Arg const& arg) {
    { pure(arg) } -> std::same_as<App<Arg>>;
};

template <typename T>
struct Maybe {
    Maybe(T const&) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct DifferentMaybe {
    DifferentMaybe(T const&) {}
};
```

You can "define" `pure(int)` and `pure(float)` later like this:

```cpp
// "define" pure(int) -> Maybe<int>
template<>
struct Pure<int> {
    static Maybe<int> apply(int i) {
        return {i};
    }
};

// "define" pure(float) -> DifferentMaybe<float>
template<>
struct Pure<float> {
    static DifferentMaybe<float> apply(float f) {
        return {f};
    }
};

// These asserts will pass.
static_assert(Applicative<Maybe,int>);
static_assert(Applicative<DifferentMaybe,float>);
```

**[Live demo (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/veTffr7o7)**

This works as expected because the specialization of `Pure<T>` is selected in the scope of where the template is *instanciated* (in this case at the `static_assert`), not in the scope of where the concept is *defined*.